# Black screen after splash

Tags: android, kotlin, splash-screen

When I open the app, the splash is shown and then there is a black screen (for just 1 second), and then goes to the activity.  How can I avoid this black screen?

I set the splash as a theme.

```
class SplashActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        if (sharedPrefs.isUserLogged) {
            startActivity(intentFor<MainActivity>().clearTask().newTask())
        }else{
            startActivity(intentFor<LoginActivity>().clearTask().newTask())
        }
        finish()
    }
}
```

I set the splash style on my AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity android:name=".view.splash.SplashActivity"
                  android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Launch">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

and in my style, I set a drawable for the background.

```
<style name="AppTheme.Launch">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/my_splash</item>
</style>
```

Comment: tried <item name="android:windowDisablePreview">true</item>?

Comment: Why don't you set drawable in the splash activity layout? Maybe changing styles causes delay.

Comment: @ShwetaChauhan yes, but this skip the splash

Comment: @underoid I was following this tutorial https://android.jlelse.eu/the-complete-android-splash-screen-guide-c7db82bce565 

If I set the drawable in the layout, there is a white screen before the splash and no black screen.

Comment: Try setting the same style for Main and Login activities and make sure their layout covers whole screen. I guess this way while second activity creates you will continue to see splash drawable instead of black screen.

Comment: @underoid I tried that. But the transition is still black

Comment: Did you tried after removing .clearTask().newTask()? Also, if screen is black for a long time, it means your MainActivity is taking too much time to be created.. Try to perform some tests with a very basic layout on MainActivity then add all the code again etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found  a solution after a while:

```
class SplashActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    Timer().schedule(1000) {
       if (sharedPrefs.isUserLogged) {
           startActivity(intentFor<MainActivity>().clearTask().newTask())
       }else{
           startActivity(intentFor<LoginActivity>().clearTask().newTask())
       }
    }
  }
}
```

and I set the theme like this:

```
<style name="AppTheme.Launch">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/my_splash</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```